# Filter debug console output in VS code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Is this feature still not created? I am getting bunch of useless info (e.g. when I test google map I get message every few seconds) and it is very anoying. Android studio has this for standard apps development, not sure about flutter. Do others have problem with this and how do you solve it?

Comment: Perhaps the new v1.49 filter debug console functionality will help - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63781319/836330

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** There is now a filter in VS Code - see comments on this answer.

---

There is not currently any feature to filter the output in the debug console. It's not expected to fill up how you're describing, though a similar issue has been raised about ads here:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1980

I haven't yet managed to figure out why there is so much output - Flutter is filtering the output that's sent to VS Code and the messages in that issue don't seem like they should match the filter. Subscribe to that issue for updates that would probably solve this issue too.

Comment: FYI: A basic Debug Console filter was released 4 days ago. Upgrade VSCode to pick it up: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/102704

Comment: This is truly "basic" filter, it's good step in right direction. I would've say MS could make a bit advanced solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of the 1.49 filter, another interesting Debug console feature is comins with VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)

> ### [Debug Console: collapse identical lines](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/c1e4683c6a35101bf09f22b6f02c5b2019ddb5eb/release-notes/v1_52.md#debug-console-collapse-identical-lines)

> Debug console now collapses identical output by showing the count of how many times it occurred.
> This feature should make it much easier to make sense of very repetitive program output.
>
> [image: Debug Console collapse]