# Flutter - how to filter debug console in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

For a few days, and without changing anything, at least deliberately, in `DEBUG CONSOLE` in `VSCODE` I get messages like:

```
W/.arae_blueprin(14366): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/.arae_blueprin(14366): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/.arae_blueprin(14366): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/.arae_blueprin(14366): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
D/EGL_emulation(14366): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1641400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5f83710)
D/EGL_emulation(14366): eglMakeCurrent: 0xc1f7c2e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xbd495c10)
D/eglCodecCommon(14366): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 6 (6) 0 0
W/.arae_blueprin(14366): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/DynamiteModule(14366): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21200
I/DynamiteModule(14366): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21200
D/eglCodecCommon(14366): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 4 (4) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon(14366): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
D/eglCodecCommon(14366): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
D/eglCodecCommon(14366): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 4 (4) 1 30
```

These messages make it difficult for me to read the logs that I send by console.

How can I filter them so they don't appear, or at least filter my own logs?. Thanks.

Comment: Same here. After update to the latest version of flutter, the debug console becomes overwhelmed. Flutter version: 1.12.13+hotfix.8

Comment: Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Also looking for a fix

Comment: So brutal.  There's been a lot of tickets filed about it which appear to trace back to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50808.  Hopefully it gets some attention so we can actually read our logs again.

Answer (score 7):

The ability to filter the Debug Console text is coming to v1.49 (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_49.md#debug-console-filter):

> Debug console now supports filtering. This should make it easier for
> users to find the output they are looking for in the Debug Console and
> to be able to hide irrelevant logs. Filter also supports the exclude
> patterns which should be prefixed with `!`. User evaluations are not
> respecting the filter and are always shown. Like other input boxes in
> VS Code you can use `up` and `down` arrow to navigate between old
> filter inputs.

[image: filter debug console demo]

Comment: Do you know how to remember the last filter? I mean thanks anyway with the arrows to navigate to the last one

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93750) issue it looks like it is not currently possible to filter the debug console in Visual Studio Code, however you could use the filter text field in the logging tab of the Dart DevTools in order to filter the logs that are sent to the console. I appreciate that this means that you would need to have the Dart DevTools open in addition to Visual Studio Code, however this would be a useable workaround until such a time as the ability to filter the debug console is implemented in Visual Studio Code.

[image: Dart DevTools]

Answer (score 2):

A basic Debug Console filter was released 4 days ago. Upgrade VSCode to pick it up: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/102704

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure to update your VS code version to the latest release and then watch this video that shows you how you can filter out the unnecessary logs:
https://streamable.com/tvatmz

Basically, if you have a log that looks like this:

```
cat cat 
dog dog
```

and you only want to keep the logs with cat you just type **cat in the filter box** or simply type **!dog**

Answer (score 1):

With the latest Flutter SDK, I kept seeing these in the log:

```
D/EGL_emulation(17171): app_time_stats: avg=499.23ms min=498.78ms max=499.94ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation(17171): app_time_stats: avg=500.12ms min=498.87ms max=501.36ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation(17171): app_time_stats: avg=500.07ms min=499.02ms max=501.11ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation(17171): app_time_stats: avg=499.90ms min=499.07ms max=500.33ms count=3
```

To filter these out in, I put `!app_time_stats:` in the Filter textfield:
[image]

This results in everything but those lines being shown in the debug console.