# How to set log level of debug console in Visual Studio Code to exclude console.debug and include console.info?

Tags: logging, visual-studio-code, console

all my calls are getting logged.  I can't find how to only show info level logging and exclude debug level.  Thanks!

Comment: You will be able to filter the debug console in  v1.49 - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63781319/836330 .  You can't set the filter before-hand but it does have a history of previously-used filters.

Answer (score 3):

There is more "log level" control coming in v1.73, you will have to see if the various categories work for you.  From [v1.73 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_73.md#setting-log-level-per-log-output-channel)

> #### Setting Log Level per Log Output Channel
>
> You can now set log level per log output channel using the command
> `Developer: Set Log Level...`. This is useful when you want to see
> more logs only from a specific log output channel.
>
> You can also set log level per extension from the command line. This
> is useful when you want to see more logs from a specific extension.
> For example the following script allows you to start VS Code with
> default log level set to `debug` for the log output channels from the
> Git extension.
>
> `bash code --log vscode.git:debug`

[image: output channel log levels]

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the log level in the console GUI itself.

For Google Chrome see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/log#filter

The debug messages are called `Verbose` messages.

For other browsers there have to be a similar GUI element.

Comment: I mean specifically for visual studio code debug console window.

Comment: I should specify- only server side logging calls.

Comment: @Mike Add a feature request for VSC to add something similar to what Chome has for filtering log-level