# How to hide specific String Output in VSCode Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting spammed with these 2 lines

```
V/AudioManager(10244): getStreamMaxVolume  treamType: 3
V/AudioManager(10244): getStreamVolume  streamType: 3 volume: 3
```

in my Terminal and I would like to hide these 2 messages because it makes reading my own outputs nearly impossible. This is the launch.json for flutter:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "habit_app_new",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there some kind of "filter" option in VSCode?

Comment: Depends on the source of the messages. Are you debugging a program? If so, what does the launch configuration look like?

Comment: I am debugging a Flutter Mobile-App

Comment: Please show the launch configuration in your question

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I have added the content of launch.json, is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used dart or flutter, but [this answer for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259610/flutter-how-to-filter-debug-console-in-vscode/63781319#63781319) seems spot on.

I think it should work for you.

Comment: I really don't understand why this didn't come up on my research. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: It took some digging for me to find it.